# Fetch plan aka. fetch group aka. entity graph in QueryDSL

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

I was unable to find any way of implementing fetch plans in QueryDSL, and I tried a lot. Can you provide me any hints? Also, do you know any better way of chosing which fields to fetch and which load lazily in different situations? I use batch fetching, therefore I can't use JOIN FETCH.

Comment: Fetch groups are not standardized in JPA or do you mean something else? Querydsl JPA supports standard JPA features and Hibernate's extensions for Hibernate's native API.

Comment: in JPA it is called fetch group, see http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.3/apache-openjpa-1.0.3/docs/manual/ref_guide_fetch.html

Comment: No, that's an OpenJPA specific extension as the docs also mention.

Comment: so there is not any alternative to it supported by querydsl?

Comment: The declarative fetch group configuration of OpenJPA will also work with Querydsl, but anything that involves casting a JPA query to an OpenJPA specific API is not supported.

Comment: I'm sorry, I ment Entity Graph from JPA, it's very similar to OpenJPA fetch group. Entity graph was introduced in JPA 2.1, chapter 3.7 in official documentation.

Comment: Querydsl supports JPA query hints, so it should work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With an EntityGraph definition like this

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "post",
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode("title"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "comments", subgraph = "comments")
    },
    subgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(
                name = "comments",
                attributeNodes = {
                    @NamedAttributeNode("content")}
        )
    }
)
```

the `EntityGraph` instance can be activated like this on the Querydsl query

```
EntityGraph postGraph = em.getEntityGraph("post");
query.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", postGraph)
```

source: http://hantsy.blogspot.fi/2013/12/jpa-21-entity-graph.html

Comment: I guess it'd be a nice addition to QueryDSL to allow for the *definition* of entity graphs in a fluent manner. There is the `EntityGraph` API in JPA which allows to do it, but it's not fluent/DSL-ish.