# QueryDSL and JPA 2.1 Entity Graph

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

In my Spring Data/JPA query I need to add filtering with many criteria and the user can choose whatever he want.

Is there a way to get working together QueryDSL and JPA 2.1 Entity Graph ? If so, could you please show an example ?

Comment: Maybe JPA Criteria API instead of QueryDSL will be helpfull?

Comment: Also, I have found info that QueryDSL supports JPA query hints and Entity Graph can  potentially be applied there.. I need to check this solution also -   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405897/fetch-plan-aka-fetch-group-aka-entity-graph-in-querydsl

Comment: JPA Support in QueryDSL - http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html#jpa_integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some code from my project using JPA Criteria API. Main idea that user can choose any field as filter and in service layer all filters are passed as `List<Map<String, Object>>`, where `String` key in map is a name of field and `Object` value is filter value. Maybe it will be helpfull:

```
public List<DocumentsShort> findAllByCriteria(Integer firstResult, Integer maxResult, String sort, String condition, List<Map<String, Object>> conditions) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<EntityClass> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(EntityClass.class);
    Root<EntityClass> root = criteriaQuery.from(EntityClass.class);
    Join<EntityClass, AnotherEntityClass> AnotherEntityClassJoin = root.join("fieldOfEntity", JoinType.LEFT);
    Predicate predicate = cb.conjunction();
    List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map<String, Object> map : conditions) {
        Predicate tempPredicate = cb.conjunction();
        tempPredicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.equal(root.get("deleted"), 0)); // only entities not marked as deleted
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Path pathToField = null;
            pathToField = root.get(key);
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            if (value == null) {
                tempPredicate = cb.and(tempPredicate, cb.isNull(pathToField));
            } else if (value instanceof String) {
                tempPredicate = cb.and(tempPredicate, cb.like(pathToField, "%" + value + "%"));
            } else if (value instanceof List) {
                tempPredicate = cb.and(tempPredicate, pathToField.in(((List) value)));
            } else {
                tempPredicate = cb.and(tempPredicate, cb.equal(pathToField, value));
            }
        }
        predicateList.add(tempPredicate);
    }
    criteriaQuery.where(cb.or(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[predicateList.size()])));
    TypedQuery query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    query.setFirstResult(firstResult != null ? firstResult : 0);
    query.setMaxResults(maxResult != null ? maxResult : 500);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```